# Optimise Round Up/Down Function

Tags: javascript, performance, for-loop, rounding

So one of our clients (an auctioneer) has a set of weird increments (also know as London increments), where essentially they don't conform to any divisible number, so using something like: `Math.round(number / increment) * increment` will not work.

The increments

```
From: 100, To: 299, Increment: 10
From: 300, To: 319, Increment: 20
From: 320, To: 379, Increment: 30
From: 380, To: 419, Increment: 20
```

And this kind of thing goes on.

So taking a number like: `311` should round up to `320`. Now I have this code and it works fine, it also rounds up/down `321 => 350` and `363 => 380` as expected.

My concern is that it is not fast and/or sustainable and with large numbers that need to be rounded it will get slower. This function needs to be as fast as the `Math.round()` obviously knowing that it won't but as fast as possible. Now as much as I got it working, the way I have done it is essentially looping X amount of times (x being any number, so I have set it to 9999999, and I am hoping someone knows a better way of doing this.

```
// Get increment amount
window.getIncrement = (num) => {
    var num = parseInt(num);
    for (var i = 0; i < window.increments.length; i++) {
        if (num >= parseInt(window.increments[i].from) && num <= parseInt(window.increments[i].to)) {
            return parseInt(window.increments[i].increment);
        }
    }
}

// Get increment start value
window.getIncrementStartValue = (num) => {
    var num = parseInt(num);
    for (var i = 0; i < window.increments.length; i++) {
        if (num >= parseInt(window.increments[i].from) && num <= parseInt(window.increments[i].to)) {
            return parseInt(window.increments[i].from);
        }
    }
};

// Custom round up function
const roundToNearestIncrement = (increment, number, roundDown) => {
    var incrementStart = parseInt(window.getIncrementStartValue(number));
    var increment = parseInt(increment), number = parseInt(number);
    console.log(incrementStart, increment, number);

    // So now we have a start value, check the direction of flow
    var lastBelow = false, firstAbove = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < 9999999; i++) {
        var incrementRounder = incrementStart + (increment * i);
        if (incrementRounder === number) { return number; }
        if (incrementRounder < number) { lastBelow = incrementRounder; }
        if (incrementRounder > number) { firstAbove = incrementRounder; }
        if (lastBelow !== false && firstAbove !== false) { break; }
        console.log('Loop #' + i + ', Below: ' + lastBelow + ', Above: ' + firstAbove);
    }
    return !roundDown ? firstAbove : lastBelow;
}
```

Then you use it like so:

```
// Example usage
var num = 329;
var inc = getIncrement(num);
console.log('Rounded: ' + roundToNearestIncrement(inc, num) + ', Expected: 350');
```

Now as I said it works great, but my concern is that it will slow down a Node process if the number uses something large like `1,234,567`, or just the highest number of that increment set, because the code will loop until it finds the above and below number, so if anyone has a better idea on how to do this that it will work but not loop?

See screenshot of the one I did before:

[image: Looping code fail]

You can see it had to loop 1865 times before it found the above and below amounts.

Anyway, any ideas you have would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of making this faster

1.You can store a very big hash will all the possible values and the rounding result. This will use a lot of scape, but will be the fastest. This means that you'll a hash similar to this

```
rounded = []; rounded[0]=0 ... rounded[100] = rounded[101] = ... = rounded[109] = 110 ... and so on.
```

Of course this solution depends on the size of the table.

2.Build a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree), based on the breakout points and search that tree. If the tree is balanced it will take O(log(n)) for a search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly:

1. Pre-build the array of all the thresholds, in ascending order. I imagine it'll look something like [0, 1, 2,..., 320, 350, 380, 400, 420,...];
2. Then the lookup will be simple:

```
const findNearestThreshold = (number) => thresholdsArray
   .find(threshold => (threshold >= number));
```

Comment: That array could be huge though? I mean we accept bids on items up to 999 million.

Comment: True, it could get large, and slower than it has to be. I'm posting a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A solution basing just on the increments array.

```
const steps = [
   { from: 100, increment: 10}, // I don't need 'to' property here
   { from: 300, increment: 20},
   { from: 320, increment: 30},
   { from: 380, increment: 20},   
]

const roundUp = x => {
   const tooLargeIndex = steps.findIndex(({from}) => from > x);
   const { from, increment } = steps[tooLargeIndex - 1];
   const difference = x - from;
   return from + Math.ceil(difference / increment) * increment;
}

console.log(300, roundUp(300));
console.log(311, roundUp(311));
console.log(321, roundUp(321));
```

Comment: Does this not cause the same problem though? If there is a large gap between the starting "from" number, e.g. 1000 and the increment changes around 10000, and the increments are 100, that is still a lot of looping to get to it, or am I reading that code wrong?